# Matlab, load adjacency lists (irregular file)

Tags: matlab

I have already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325006/matlab-reading-irregular-textfile) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787427/read-load-parts-of-the-irregular-file-by-matlab), but I'm not sure I found what I need.

I have an irregular file (that represents neighbors of particles 1 to 5) that looks like that

```
2 3 5
1 3
1 2

1
```

I am want to figure out a way to load it (as 'something' called `A`) and do the following things:

1. Count the number of elements on one line (for instance `size(A(1,:))` shall give me `3`)
2. Given an array `B` (of size 5) select the elements of B corresponding to the indices given by a line (something like `B(A(1,:))` shall give me `[B(2) B(3) B(5)]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want arrays with size depending on their first index, you're probably left with `cell`s. Your cell `A` could be such that `A{1}` equals to `[2 3 5]` and `A{2}` to `[1 3]` in your example etc. To do this you can read your file `infile` by

```
fid=fopen(infile,'rt');
A=[];
while 1
    nextline=fgets(fid);
    if nextline==-1 %EOF reached
        break;
    end
    A{end+1}=sscanf(nextline,'%d');
end
fclose(fid);

%demonstrate use for indexing
B=randi(10,5,1);
B(A{3}) %2-element vector
B(A{4}) %empty vector
```

Then `A{i}` is a vector corresponding to the `i`th line in your file. If the line is empty, then it's the empty vector. You can use it to index `B` as you want to, see the example above. Note that you should not add a newline at the very end of your `infile`, otherwise you'll have a spurious empty element for `A`. If you know in advance how many lines you need to read, this is not an issue.

And the number of entries in line `i` are given by `length(A{i})`, with `i=1:length(A)`.

Comment: Thanks! I guess my problem was to understand what is a cell… And to avoid getting `NaN` from `textscan` ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325006/matlab-reading-irregular-textfile) )

Comment: I don't really like cells, they are very counter-intuitive for me. For instance, watch out for `A(1)` vs `A{1}`, since the former is a cell with a single vector in it, while the latter is the vector itself.